# cannot read property 'channel' of null with simpleweather.js

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using simpleweather plugin for displaying current weather and worked fine till yesterday. Now it shows error as 'cannot read property 'channel' of null'. When I debugged the script, I found that the yahoo data fails to retrieve saying service unavailable hence query.results.channel is null. Can anyone solve my issue? Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_catalogs/masterpage/NMSTheme/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_catalogs/masterpage/NMSTheme/js/jquery.simpleWeather.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_catalogs/masterpage/NMSTheme/js/yqlgeo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            loadWeather();
            setInterval(loadWeather, 6000);
        });     

        function loadWeather() {
        debugger;
            if(navigator.geolocation){

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                    var location = (position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
                    var woeid = undefined;

                    $.simpleWeather({
                        location: location,
                        woeid: woeid,
                        unit: 'f',
                        success: function (weather) {
                        var time = ReturnCurrentTime();
                        placehtml = '<span><h5>' + weather.city + ',' + weather.region + '</h5><span/>';
                        datehtml = '<span><h5> ' + weather.forecast[0].day + ',' + time + '</h5><span/>';
                        html = '<span><h5> ' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + ' ' + weather.units.temp + '</h5><span/>' ;

                        $("#date").html(datehtml);
                        $("#place").html(placehtml);
                        $("#weather").html(html);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        $("#weather1").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
                    }
                });
            });
            }
        }       
    </script>
```

Comment: Looks like they are having some troubles https://github.com/monkeecreate/jquery.simpleWeather/issues/101#issuecomment-173530978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo have introduced a bug into `geo.placefinder` querying. Use `geo.places`.

replace line 26 in simpleWeather.js with:

```
weatherUrl += 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text="'+options.location+'" limit 1) and u="'+options.unit+'"';
```

If you are calling with geolocation lat/long surround options.location with parentheses:

```
$.simpleWeather({
    location: '(' + lat_long + ')',
```

See more on simpleWeather issues in Github:

https://github.com/monkeecreate/jquery.simpleWeather/issues/174

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo seems to have discontinued the geolocation services needed to find a location based on latitude and longitude. Using simpleWeather's woeid property instead of location still works, though.